# CardView item truncated because of its length

Tags: java, android, listview, cardview

I have an expandable CardView, and if I have a long string when it is expanded, it gets truncated to the height of the previous ListView, as you can see on the photos:

- Titles

  [image]
- Expanded

  [image]

What can I do to solve?

If you need more info, just ask!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: link to XMLs (really long) https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WNbfIP09Xaiiu_FGs9ykaDqtVBT_fubgOZ83uccvZSE/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: What is the kind of container you are using for displaying your CardItems? Is it a RecyclerView? And have you checked that the container does not have a margin, or not other View is getting drawn on top of your container? Because that is what seems to be happening here. Please provide your View XML and that can be helpful.

Comment: post your layout file here, whichever is being used by your images.

Comment: @NehaK XMLs provided just now, can you please help me?

Comment: try to remove android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" from your list